# Wordpress pagination based on category

Tags: categories, pagination

I have the following custom pagination for my galleries.

http://pastebin.com/MnypvU6P

Now when I open my galleries, I can press next and previous and it works but it loops through posts in all categories, how can I limit it to categories?

For example if I have a category called "Weddings" I want the next and previous to show only galleries in that category.

Comment: Please put the code in the question.

Comment: @ialocin the code is in the pastebin link

Comment: You can't expect people to follow links to see your code, so it is better to put directly into the question, after all you want to make it easy for the people helping you.

Comment: @ialocin I added in pastebin because it's too long for stackoverflow + everyone knows about pastebin

Comment: Your decision, I was just trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The functions [`next_post_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [`previous_post_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) have the parameters `$in_same_term` and `$taxonomy` for that purpose.